# Gmail ask every 20s for SMS permission

Tags: gmail, permissions

Since the last update on my Huawei to Android 6.0, and even after configuring things properly, Gmail is displaying a message every 20 seconds asking for me to activate the sms permission.
The problem is that I already activated it !

How to get rid of these annoying and wrong messages?

Comment: Are you sure it's Gmail? Gmail app only has permissions for Calendar, Contacts and Storage. Please post a screen-shot or steps you follow to get to that point.

Comment: You are right, the dialog asks for permissions but then redirects me to the Google Play Services permissions. Here the SMS permission was checked. I removed it, and activated it again. It looks like it is working now.